# Passing a param to handlePress gives handlePress is not a function

Tags: react-native

I am trying to pass a param to my handlePush inside the recipe constant and get handlePush is not a function

```
const Recipe = ({ name, durationLabel, numberOfServings, handlePress, keepBubble, handlePush }) => (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => handlePush(keepBubble)}>
            <View syle={{ justifyContent:'center'}}>
                {keepBubble ? (
                <Image
                source={require("app/assets/icons/bubbleOff.png")}
                style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}
                />)
                : (
                < Image
                source = {require("app/assets/icons/bubbleOn.png")}
                style={{justifyContent:'center'}}
            />)}
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

And My function is as follows

```
handlePush(keepBubble){
    console.log("BUBBLES", keepBubble);
};
```

Comment: Ive updated @Tim let me know if this is enough

Comment: @AnthonyMarino unfortunately, this is still not sufficient. Please have a look on here: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe you can provide a https://snack.expo.io/?